# Speeding up object name check by record ID

Tags: apex

I have been able to piece together some code that determines object name based on record ID without any hard-coding or SOQL.  It works with both custom and standard objects *but it is very slow*, I'm guessing due to loading so much schema data and a lot of looping.

I am looking for a way to speed this function up, potentially by limiting the object names searched or the amount of data being sorted through.

Here is the entire (working, but slow) function:

```
// Get sObject type by record ID
public static String getObjName(String recordId) {
    // Get record prefix
    String recordPrefix = recordId.substring(0, 3);

    // Get global "describe"
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    // Loop through all objects to find match for record ID prefix
    for (Schema.SObjectType otype : gd.values()) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = otype.getDescribe();
        String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();

        // Found match!
        if (prefix != null && prefix.equals(recordPrefix)) return r.getName();
    }

    return '';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Id`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) class already contains an instance method to do exactly what you wish, named `getSObjectType`. The entire body of your method can be simplified to the below:

```
return (recordId == null) ? '' : String.valueOf(recordId.getSObjectType());
```

---

Better than returning the name of the `SObjectType` as a string would be to use static typing and directly return the result:

```
public static SObjectType getSObjectType(Id recordId)
{
    return recordId?.getSObjectType();
}
```